# Unable to perform cross domain request in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, wcf, xmlhttprequest, web-config

I have created two Web Projects name them **WebJSONSender(port 82)** and **WebConsumer(port 85)**. Using JSON Serializers and WCF I am able to send JSON from WebJSONSender and use it in my web pages from WebJSONSender(using jQuery and/or AngularJS).

When I try to access the same part from WebConsumer It tells me

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load `http://localhost:82/App_Dynamic_Resource~PREST,app.rest.user.svc/DoWork`. No Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is present on the requested resource. Origin `http://localhost:85` is therefore not allowed access.

I searched on Google and StackOverflow but lots of the response I received was to use JSONP, some CORS stuff and others which I could not understand (My Fault).

I tried putting following stuff in my $http (angular) call but to no success.

```
headers:
{ 
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*' , 
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods':'GET, POST'
}
```

I tried putting some parts in my web.config (Port 82), but with no success. And now I have removed both the changes.

I want to ask what changes am I required to do and in which application (Port 82 and/or Port 85).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got is solved finally.

There are two solution for this problem. Also note that setting has to be done on the server whom you want to access in my case **WebJSONSender(port 82)**. You can either do is using web.config or Global.asax file. I do not why but when I tried it using web.config or Global.asax it did not worked.

But when I tried both simultaneously it worked like charm.

**web.config**

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

**Global.asax**

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Allow Access Control from all origins
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    //Only if HttpMethod is Options (pre-flight OPTIONS call sent by browser in some cases and jQuery) Allow Cross Site Requests for GET/POST
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept");
        //This is only to allow browser to cache this response and send pre-flight request only after 20 days (you can change it as per your convenience)
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    }
}
```

Ideally they both are doing the same thing with one exception in Global.asax that it sends this extra response only in case of **OPTIONS HttpMethod** (pre-flight request). I assume that some of other settings in my application was preventing this to work correctly earlier.

Answer (score 1):

The browser can't make cross domain JavaScript calls.  This is done to avoid [cross-site scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_site_scripting) calls.

The most common work around I've seen is to use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).  I'm not sure what you read or why you didn't understand it.  In the context of AngularJS, it is very easy to do using the [JSONP](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http#jsonp) helper method.

A JSONP call is, essentially, the same as a get call; so create the URL with all relevant URL parameters and make the call:

```
$http.jsonp('http://mydomain.com/myendpoint.aspx?someparameter=value&otherparameter=value2&callback=JSON_CALLBACK').
success(function(data, status) {
      console.log(status);
      console.log(data);
    })
)'
```

The thing to keep in mind is that the JSONP callback function in AngularJS is a fixed value, and must always be JSON_CALLBACK.  You may have to re-write your server side code to wrap the results returned in the JSONP function, like this:

```
JSON_CALLBACK(myExpectedResults);
```

The AngularJS helper method makes a lot of the 'setup' needed for JSONP calls go away.  Otherwise you'd have to create your own callback function:

```
function JSON_CALLBACK(data){
  // processing callback data here
}
```

Does that help?

Comment: I think there is some 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' settings which is done in web.config which allows app to do cross site scripting. You provide list of domains [to]which can perform Cross site scripting. I want to know how to perform that setting and where. I do not want to go through JSONP as I will have to change existing server side code which is tested and being used in many apps. I also do not want to create a wrapper to perform the same as well.

Comment: @DurgeshChaudhary A it of Googling makes me think that may be a part of CORS; which is an alternate to JSONP.  ( http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api ); but it is a bit beyond my realm of personal experience. I assume that the config will have to be on the server being accessed [not the server hosting the app].  Similar to a crossdomain.xml file for Flex or a clientaccesspolicy.xml for Silverlight.  But, at this point I'm just guessing.

Comment: I also assume the same, setting has to be done on WebJSONSender in example given above. I will try more tomorrow in the office to get it done. Thanks anyways and will update as I make progress